# Default nodata value in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I want to set the nodata value in the layer transparency properties to 0, meaning that every new added layer will have this value as a default as opposed to the situation today where this value is blank by default: [image: default layer settings]
is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your settings, head for the `processing` tab, open the `general` dropdown menu and add a path to a raster style (which you need to create before, obvisously).

[image]

Comment: How do I create new raster style?

Comment: Style a raster as you like, then save it as qml.